# Unable to use active record time methods inside ruby on rails 5.0 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

I'm currently unable to use any of the active support time methods inside my ruby on rails 5.0 model like the following:

```
5.seconds
2.days
10.minutes
```

throws an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `seconds' for AS::Duration:0x007f97a5903b90 @value=5, @parts=[[:seconds, 5]] Did you mean?  send

EDIT: here is the actual code causing an issue.

```
ReminderJob.set(wait: 5.seconds).perform_later(self.user.id)
```

Even tho I can see people using the below code fine and it works

```
UserReminderJob.set(wait: 1.week).perform_later user
```

However, it works in my console and in my controllers and views.

Comment: Those methods comes from `ActiveSupport` not `ActiveRecord`. Please add more context to your question. What you do and what is not working.

Comment: Please show the actual code that's not working, because that error says you're (presumably indirectly) calling `5.seconds.seconds`, which does not match your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that the object is **`AS::Duration:0x007f97a5903b90`**, **NOT** an integer -- therefore the example of `5.seconds` will not reproduce the problem.

This is also unusual, since `5.seconds` will normally return an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object, not `AS::Duration`.

I would therefore hazard a guess that you're actually using the [`as-duration` ruby gem](https://github.com/janko-m/as-duration) rather than built-in rails behaviour. This [extends the the `Integer` class in a different way](https://github.com/janko-m/as-duration/blob/b50cf856e5444d8d840eab583b14d04401d3bc5a/lib/as/duration/core_ext/numeric.rb#L2-L4), and returns an object that doesn't behave like an integer.

I think that an actual reproduction of your error could be achieved with: `5.seconds.seconds`. In standard rails, this works fine (and returns the same value as `5.seconds`), since `ActiveSupport::Duration` instances behave like `Integer`s. But with this gem, it fails with the above error.

Comment: I just edited my question with the exact code causing an error.

Comment: You didn't show the **full** error. I'll bet you anything that the error does not originate from that line, but rather, from somewhere inside the job that calls `wait.seconds`. I also explained why this would work fine in standard rails code. If you wish to continue using this gem, a quick fix could just be to call `serReminderJob.set(wait: 5)` -- but frankly, given the nature of this error, I'd be inclined to not use that gem!

Comment: Ok thanks I'm currently using 5 instead of 5.seconds but it gets a little messy when referring to multiple days or weeks.

Comment: You could also try forking that gem / writing your own extension, to add behaviour like above - i.e. `class ActiveSupport::Duration; def seconds; self; end`. This would allow chaining methods like `5.seconds.seconds == 5.seconds`.